# How do I Impersonate the logged in user within a WCF service hosted in a windows service?

Tags: c#, wcf, service, uwp

I have a WCF Service hosted inside of a Windows Service on Windows 10 that makes calls to SQL Server.  I use this service within a UWP application and it works perfectly if the service is logged in as the current user.  However, I do not want to run the service on the client using the client's credentials because they change.  I want to run the service as a local system account and run each operation in the WCF service (running inside the windows service) as the user that is currently logged in to the machine.

Everything is running on the client machine, including the database.  There are no remote calls if that makes any difference.

I have tried setting `impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true"` in the WCF Service app.config and/or `[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]` in the service file and the windows service will not start with either or these options.

I have not had to implement a system like this before. This is all because I have to use SQL Server as the database in a UWP app. If there is a better way let me know.

If anyone has any idea if this can be done without running the service as the current user I would appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean "the service is logged in as the current user"? At first, you said "I do not want to install and run the service on the client". Then you said "Everything is running on the client machine". So I'm confused with what you want to do. Could you clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: Sorry.  When I start the windows service as the currently logged on user it works.  When I start the service as local system it does not work because of permissions.  I want to run the service with a local system account, but have all of the calls in the WCF service (running within the windows service) use the locally logged in user to execute.  When I say everything is running on the client machine all calls in the service send and receive data to a local database, no remote database so everything is stored directly on the machine...I thought this might be helpful information.  Thank you.